# get all Combinations of length N out of M

Tags: r, combinations

I'm searching for a simple way to get all possible unique combinations of the length N out of M.

Here a simple example:

```
M <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
N <- 2
```

Expected output:

```
1, 2
1, 3 
1, 4
1, 5
2, 3
2, 4
2, 5
3, 4
3, 5
4, 5
```

Comment: What did you google that `combn` didn't come up right away?

Comment: Note that `combn` returns all combinations 'without replacement', which is what you requested.  `expand.grid` returns all combinations 'with replacement': `expand.grid(x1=c(1:5), x2=c(1:5))`.  I do not know whether `combn` can return all combinations 'with replacement'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `combn` function

```
> n <- 1:5
> combn(n, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same result as @jdharrison's example.

`combnPrim` is quite a bit faster as rapidly hands over to `.C`, although clearly this is overkill for an example where only one small combination is required.

```
library(gRbase)
### the following dependencies may be necessary, install as follows:
### source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
### biocLite("graph")
### biocLite("BiocGenerics")
### biocLite("RBGL")
gRbase::combnPrim(seq(5), 2)
```